# Tailwind CSS appears different on production versus development preview

Tags: tailwind-css, svelte, cloudflare, production, postcss

I'm developing a svelte-kit, tailwind, postcss, daisyUI webapp for Cloudflare pages. In development and production preview, the app looks great.

However, when the app get's deployed to production, the text size becomes much larger, though when inspected both text is 8rem. I suspect the root text-size size must be different but I'm not sure.

Svelte Page:

```
<script lang="ts">
</script>

<div
  class="min-w-screen min-h-screen grid grid-cols-4 bg-gradient-to-r from-primary to-secondary"
>
  <div class="text-center col-start-1 col-end-3">
    <h1 class="text-white md:text-left tracking-[.40em] font-bold text-6xl my-6 md:text-9xl md:my-96 md:px-96">
      Your Solar Services
    </h1>
    <h2 class="text-white text-right tracking-[.20em] md:tracking-[.10em] text-4xl md:text-left md:text-9xl md:mt-96 md:px-96">
      Your Power. Your Rules. Your Freedom.
    </h2>
    <h2 class="text-white text-right underline tracking-[.1em] md:tracking-[.10em] md:text-left text-3xl 
            md:text-9xl md:mt-80 md:px-96">
        Our Goal is to provide you with the best solar services in the industry.
        Our certified agents can be reached at yoursolarservices@sunmail.com. For a free consultation.
      </h2>
    <button class="btn-primary w-4/6 h-96 mt-64 text-9xl text-white">
        Book Your Free Meeting Now!
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-start-3 col-end-5">
    <img
      class="w-max h-max object-contain min-w-full"
      src="/sun_icon.webp"
      alt="Solar Services Icon"
    />
    </div>
</div>
<div>
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
</div>
```

Tailwind config:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  important: true,
  content: ['./src/**/*.{html,js,svelte,ts}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [require("daisyui")],
  daisyui: {
    themes: [
      {
        mytheme: {
          "primary": "#FFBE3D",
          "secondary": "#F06543",
          "accent": "#FFD88B",
          "neutral": "#2a323c",
          "info": "#F1F1F1",
          "success": "#36d399",
          "warning": "#fbbd23",           
          "error": "#f87272",
        },
         
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

I've tried changed the svelte adapter from cloudflare to auto, adding '!important' to the tailwind config, manually setting the text-size of the html tag to 16, and have been diving into inspect element trying to find any differences between the two pages. Also, for some reason the horizontal overflow scroll bar is present in production vs dev.

Comment: 8 rem can be different in different environments. You should check the computed font-size property in devtools. Is it bigger? If so, check your root element font-size and fix it.

Comment: @RamilMuratov Thanks for the suggestion, I didn't know about the computed section of devtools, very useful. Sadly, the computed font size is the exact same, 128px. Which is so bizarre because the production h1 is so much bigger! I'm not sure where to find the root elements font size. Is there tooling for comparing the computed section of two webpages?

Comment: @RamilMuratov Just noticed a difference! The height and width of the root layout component is significantly different in production. In production it's height 6600px and width:1054px while in development it's roughly 4000px by 4000px. currently the height and width of the root layout is not defined so I'll add a definition and see if that works.

Comment: Updating the root layouts with min-h-fit or min-h-screen did not effect the height and width in production

Comment: Try inspecting/fine tuning `line-height` property?